# Donut chart with partial ring around

Tags: d3.js

I'm building a context menu using D3.js donut chart. Now I'd like to add a submenu when mousehovering a certain element, like this (sorry for my paint skills):

[image: Menu sketch]

The main donut menu is already done, but I can't figure out how to add the submenu. It must be centered around the parent element (the element that has the subitems), because other menu items in the main menu might also have a submenu.

I already looked into this question: [D3.js - Donut charts with multiple rings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17507728/d3-js-donut-charts-with-multiple-rings) but those are full rings.

Anyone an example?

Comment: The centering around the parent element you can achieve by setting the start and end angles of the arc accordingly, i.e. adding an offset to the `d` that you pass to the arc.

Comment: care to show your code?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff don't you mean setting the `innerRadius` and `outerRadius`? These relate to the _radial_ position of the arc. The start and end angles relate to the _angular_ position of the arc, I think...

Comment: You're correct -- the radii need to be adjusted as well. This is straightforward however (you simply add a number) whereas displaying the partial arc at the right position is slightly less straightforward.

Comment: Please provide the code or implementation logic for the same.
I also had the same requirement please help me out for the same.
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to get it working! I used `startAngle`, `endAngle`, `innerRadius` and `outerRadius`.

Only the centering around the parent element isn't done yet. I just place the submenu always on top now. This is the result:

[image: Context menu]

Thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: Please share the implementation logic. I need it urgently. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Sorry quite impossible to do since it's tightly baked into our code.