# D3.js Donut Chart With Inner Rings using .csv files

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

My question is similar to that asked here : [D3.js - Donut charts with multiple rings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17507728/d3-js-donut-charts-with-multiple-rings/17507796#17507796)

In that question, there was the use of nested arrays to draw the inner rings in the posted jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Qh9X5/154/ referenced as a solution to the problem.

I am trying to implement the donut chart with inner rings but this time using a csv file. This is my current code:

```js
var margin = {top: 20, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 30},
 width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    donutWidth = 50;
    //radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

var color = d3.scale.category10(); 

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
    //.value(function(d){ return d.count;})
    .sort(null);

var arc = d3.svg.arc();
    //.innerRadius(radius - donutWidth)
    //.outerRadius(radius - 50);

var chart1 = d3.select("#chartArea1").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")"); 

d3.csv("data/svm-prediction.csv", function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  var classNames = d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "Class"; });

  data.forEach(function(d) {
      d.predValues = classNames.map(function(name) { return {name: name, value: +d[name]}; });
  });

  var gs = chart1.selectAll("g").data(d3.values(function(d){ return d.predValues; })).enter().append("g");

  var path = gs.selectAll('path')
        .data(function(d){ return pie(d); })
      .enter().append('path')
        .attr('d', function(d, i , j) { return
          arc.innerRadius(10+donutWidth*j).outerRadius(donutWidth*(j+1))(d);
        })
        .attr('fill', function(d, i) { return color(d.data.Class); });

});
```

I keep running the code, but it doesn't display on the webpage. I am trying to show the counts for the predicted and actual classes, grouped by the class names. Please assist.

This is the format of the csv file:

```
Class,Actual_Class,Predicted_Class,Accuracy
Class A,495,495,100
Class B,495,492,99
Class C,495,495,100
Class D,495,495,100
Class E,495,495,100
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to the fiddle you have posted let's try to convert the data we get from our csv into arrays of data for actual values and predicted values. I am sure that there might be better ways to do this but a simple, straight forward approach will be as follows:

```
var donutData = new Array,
    actualValues = new Array,
    predValues = new Array;

data.forEach(function(d) {
  actualValues.push(d.Actual_Class);
  predValues.push(d.Predicted_Class);
});

donutData.push(actualValues);
donutData.push(predValues);
```

You won't have to do a filter on class name and all. The `donutData` object that we created (2D array) can directly be used for creating the donut charts. 
Next, while creating `gs` you are trying to use bound data without actually binding any before doing so. So replace that line with:

```
var gs = chart1.selectAll("g").data(donutData).enter().append("g");
```

Now that we have data nicely bound to `g` tags, one for each class, we can proceed with donut chart creation:

```
var path = gs.selectAll('path')
    .data(function(d){ return pie(d); })
  .enter().append('path')
    .attr('d', function(d, i , j) { 
      return arc.innerRadius(10+donutWidth*j).outerRadius(donutWidth*(j+1))(d);
    })
    .attr('fill', function(d, i) { return color(i); });
```

Notice that I have used `pie(d)` to select the corresponding arrays we constructed. Also, I have simply passed `i` to the `color()` for generating different colors. the `d3.csv()` part will look something like this:

```
d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
  if (error) console.log("error reading csv");

  var donutData = new Array,
      actualValues = new Array,
      predValues = new Array;    

  data.forEach(function(d) {
      actualValues.push(d.Actual_Class);
      predValues.push(d.Predicted_Class);
  });

  donutData.push(actualValues);
  donutData.push(predValues);

  var gs = chart1.selectAll("g").data(donutData).enter().append("g");

  var path = gs.selectAll('path')
        .data(function(d){ return pie(d); })
      .enter().append('path')
        .attr('d', function(d, i , j) { 
          return arc.innerRadius(10+donutWidth*j).outerRadius(donutWidth*(j+1))(d);
        })
        .attr('fill', function(d, i) { return color(i); });

});
```

Hope this was what you were actually looking for.

Comment: I made the changes to the code but that also didn't work.

Comment: can you check the console and find out any specific errors?

Comment: surprisingly its working now only this is almost what i'm looking for. I want to achieve two rings, with the inner ring for the distribution of the "actual class" values for each class so a partition of 5, and then the outer ring for the "predicted class" values for each class.

Comment: Oh ok. So instead of making arrays of the form `{pred value, actual value}` for each class we can make two arrays corresponding to actual and predicted values of the classes. I have made the necessary code changes to accommodate the same. Have a look now.

Comment: Glad to help. You can accept this as the answer if you found it helpful.